# How to build up height of container gradually? Framer Motion vite react TS

Tags: css, typescript, react-native, vite, framer-motion

I´m using framer Motion for the first time and also quite new to React. I want to build a nice Menu that builds up **gradually** and **pushes with each child the Content further down**. But I can´t seem to figure out why the **height jumps straight to the maxHeight** needed for every child with in Animation. The exit works wonderful the process is gradually  even though its still a little jumpy it would be nice to find a way that makes the whole animation very smooth and not laggy.

A **easeIn** and **easeOut** would be wonderful for example a **fast start and slow finish** and the opposite speed variant for the exit.

I looked on some Websites already but I think my knowledge is not big enough yet to understand what they are doing without any context. So it would be very helpful if you could explain in greater Detail so I can understand the mechanics better.

```
import {AnimatePresence, motion} from "framer-motion";
import {Kategorie} from "../models/Kategorie.tsx";
import * as React from 'react';


const menuItems = {
    initial: {opacity: 0, y: -50, margin: 0},
    animate: (index: number) => ({opacity: 1, y: 0, paddibg: `${5*index}px 0px`, transition: {delay: index * 0.2, when: "beforeChildren"}}),
    exit: (index: number) => ({opacity: 0, y: -50, padding: `${5*index}px 0px`, transition: {delay: index * 0.2, when: "afterChildren"}}),
};
const conatainer = {
    initial: {opacity: 0, y: -50, marginBottom: 0, padding: 0.5},
    animate: {
        y: 0,
        opacity: 1,
        maxHeight: 500,
        transition: {

            type: "spring",
            staggerChildren: 0.2,
            duration: 0.5,
        }
    },
    exit: {
        y: -50,
        opacity: 0,
        maxHeight:0,
        transition: {
            type: "tween",
            staggerChildren: 0.2,
            duration: 0.5,
        }
        }
    };



type KategorieMenuProps = {
    onCategoryClick: (kategorie: string) => void
}

export default function KategorieMenu({onCategoryClick}: KategorieMenuProps) {
    const kategorieList: Kategorie[] = [
        {
            kategorieName: "LAND",
            kategorieBeschreibung: "Alles was das Herz eines Fleischfressers begehrt ob Wild oder weniger ausgefallene Fleischsorten"
        },
        {
            kategorieName: "SEE",
            kategorieBeschreibung: "Ariel udn Sebastian sind halt zu schmackhaft um sie bei Disney zu versuern zu lassen!"
        },
        {
            kategorieName: "VEGETARISCH",
            kategorieBeschreibung: "Vegetarier wissen um die Versuchung von Tierischenprodukten sind aber stark genug um der Fleischeslust zu wieder stehen"
        },
        {
            kategorieName: "VEGAN",
            kategorieBeschreibung: "Tiere sind Freunde und keine Nahrung! Auch nicht ihre Produkte!"
        },
        {
            kategorieName: "SÜSS",
            kategorieBeschreibung: "Süße Robenbabys im SoßerZoo( wer kein switch reloaded kenntist vlt zu Jung)"
        },
        {
            kategorieName: "KATEGORIEN",
            kategorieBeschreibung: "Philipp and Jakobs list of Recipes from Websites, TikTok, Instagram and also own creations."
        }
    ];
    const [kategorie, setKategorie] = React.useState<Kategorie[]>(kategorieList);
    const [currentCategorie, setCurrentCategorie] = React.useState<string>(kategorieList[5].kategorieName);
    const [unfold, setUnfold] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

    function onCategorie(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) {
        setKategorie(kategorieList.filter(kategorie => kategorie.kategorieName !== event.currentTarget.value));
        const onkategorie: Kategorie = kategorieList.find(kategorie => kategorie.kategorieName === event.currentTarget.value);
        setCurrentCategorie(onkategorie.kategorieName);
        onCategoryClick(event.currentTarget.value);
        setUnfold(false);


    }


    function menuTrigger() {
        setUnfold(!unfold);
    }

    return (
        <div className="Menu">
            <div>
                <button className="flex flex-row bg-transparent text-2xl text-current" onClick={menuTrigger}>
                    <h1>{currentCategorie}</h1>
                </button>
                <AnimatePresence>
                    {unfold&& <motion.div
                            variants={conatainer}
                            initial={conatainer.initial}
                            animate={unfold? conatainer.animate :conatainer.exit}
                            className="MenuItems">
                        {kategorie.map((kat, index) => (
                            <motion.button
                                initial={menuItems.initial}
                                animate={menuItems.animate(index)}
                                exit={menuItems.exit(index)}
                                className="MenuItem bg-transparent text-2xl p-4"
                                onClick={onCategorie}
                                value={kat.kategorieName}
                                key={kat.kategorieName}>
                                {kat.kategorieName}
                            </motion.button>
                        ))}
                        </motion.div>}
                </AnimatePresence>
            </div>


            <h4>
                {kategorieList.find(kategorie => kategorie.kategorieName === currentCategorie)?.kategorieBeschreibung}
            </h4>

        </div>
    );
}
```

If you have further alterations please let me know!

Thanks for the help. Please be understanding to me as I´m quite new to this whole Community and Frameworks.